# what do the symbols (* + !) at the end of a git branch mean?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, git-branch

I sometimes notice that my git branch has suffixes of `!` or `*` or `+`. Thats probably not an exhaustive list, just a few I noticed. I think `+` means the branch is dirty, and `!` means I should pull master, but is this documented anywhere? Is there a name for these special characters?

Also, sometimes the characters don't synchronize between vscode and zsh, which adds to the confusion...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the prompt of your terminal, the information displayed depends on the extension you use to print git information in that prompt.

The `! * +` characters are not part of `git` commands, they are added by that extension, probably to indicate one of :

- current branch is up to date/ahead/behind/forked with respect to its remote branch,
- there are active conflicts needing to be resolved in your repo ...

Do you know what zsh extension you installed to have git information in your prompt ?
Check the documentation / manual for that extension.

---

About the "the characters don't synchronize between vscode and zsh" : the message displayed in the prompt is not dynamic, the only way to "refresh" it is to have your terminal display a new prompt (e.g: click in your terminal and type `[enter]`).